# simplexml_load_file() with non-standard XML file

Tags: php, xml

I'm having trouble using a non-standard XML file with simplexml_load_file(). Here's my code:

```
<?php
$file = 'http://www.gostanford.com/data/xml/events/m-baskbl/2010/index.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

echo 'Displaying user names of XML file...<br />';
foreach($xml as $event_date){
    echo 'Home: '.$event_date->hn.'<br />';
}

?>
```

As you'll see, nothing is being output from the XML file, only the echo'd "Home:"

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is a standard xml file? Could you provide a sample of the xml file in question...

Comment: More specifically, what is a "non-standard XML file"? It's either XML or it isn't. Unless you want to describe chalk as non-standard cheese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the XML data, nothing non-standard about it:

```
<game_days>
   <event_date date="20101023">
      <event id="1271699" local_time="6:00 PM PT" eastern_time="21:00" hc="stan" vc="" hn="Stanford" vn="" hs="" vs=""/>
   </event_date>
```

The attribute you are looking for is one element level `<event>` below.
And to access attributes use the array syntax instead:

```
foreach($xml as $event_date){
    echo $event_date->event['hn'];
```

Comment: Perfect - thank you Mario! Just curious, why is it better to enclose the syntax in the brackets/apostrophes? I might need to update some other files :)

Comment: It doesn't work with `->attr`. That's just how SimpleXML behaves. Attributes are only accessible using array notation, so that iterating over a node with `foreach` only returns child nodes per default. The attributes are "a bit more hidden" that way.

Answer (score 0):

If by non-standard you mean a different namespace here is what you can do:

[Namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getdocnamespaces.php)

you can get the namespace and work with it like a "standard xml"